# writing complex nested for loop in java 8

Tags: java, loops, java-8

My question is about writing a complex nested for loop in Java 8 streams.

In my nested loops, I check some condition if it's met I pop some elements from my list and I restart the loops again.

Here is the my classic code I want to refactor:

```
for (int i=0; i < dtoList.size(); i++){
   for (int j=i+1; j < dtoList.size(); j++){
      if(someVerification()){
         MyDto dto1 = dtoList.get(i); 
         MyDto dto2 = dtoList.get(j); 
         dtoList.remove(dto1);
         dtoList.remove(dto2);
         // some other treatements ...
         i=-1; // to reset the first loop
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

I tried some code with forEach but it doesn't really meet my requirements :

```
IntStream.range(0,dtoList.size()).forEach(i->
{IntStream.range(0,i)).forEach(j -> { /* how to get out from the loops ??*/})})
```

If there is any potential ameliorations for the algorithm it's welcome.

Comment: I think, in your case, `for` loop looks better and more readable.

Comment: Is there a typo?  The outer loop variable is supposed to be `i` not `j`.

Comment: no need to use streams. Moreover, I hope the code you wrote is not the original one because there are some mistakes

Comment: @balsick I'm sure (I hope) the _original_ code doesn't mean to have a `someVerification()` method ;)

Comment: `i=0;break` does not exactly reset the outer loop, because it then reaches the end of outer loop where `i++` will be executed. So the net effect is the outer loop will restart from 1 not 0. I would rewrite using `while` instead of `for`.

Comment: I know you didn't ask for this, but with java 9 you could use `takewhile`. Maybe you can find some java-8 back port somewhere...

Comment: Using streams here is actually somewhat tricky due to you wanting to mutate `i` inside the nested loop, you could maybe abuse `allMatch` to break the inside loop when a condition fails: `IntStream.range(0,i).allMatch(j -> someVerification() && dtoList.remove(i) && dtoList.remove(j))` but it's less readable and less "right" than your current method.

Comment: `someVerification()` includes use of `i` or `j` I guess?

Comment: Why does the outer loop need to restart?  Can the list be sorted based on `someVerification()`?  Then there could be a single iteration, working on `i` and `i+1` elements.

Comment: @balsick this is a pseudo code, the purpose is to find a solution for the algorithm not for how my original code is written :)

Comment: @jingx you are right, so it should be i=-1 instead

Comment: Or perhaps a multi-map with the key based on `someVerification()`.  Then 1 iteration, working on that group of elements for that key.

Comment: `dtoList.remove(i);` and `dtoList.remove(j);` doesn't make sense. As soon as you call `list.remove(i)` the element from the list will be removed and remaining elements will get a new indexes. So by the time you call  `dtoList.remove(j);` the will be a different element at index `j`

Comment: @Clijsters I was actually talking about wrong indexes usage :)

Comment: @FrankelStein sure man, I understand this, I was highlighting that pseudocodes should work in your mind, this didn&#39;t &#128513;

Comment: @AntonBalaniuc I updated my code to take your remark into account

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure of your intention behind the `remove(i)` and `remove(j)` inside your nested loop. Not an elegant solution, but a way to do the same with Stream would be as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> immutable = Arrays.asList("ABCDEAFABCDSDFQAA".split(""));

    System.out.println("Before: " + immutable.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")));

    List<String> dtoList = new ArrayList<>();
    dtoList.addAll(immutable);

    List<Integer> marks = new ArrayList<>();
    IntStream.range(0, dtoList.size())
        .filter(i -> !marks.contains(i))
        .mapToObj(integer -> integer)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(i+1, dtoList.size())
                .mapToObj(integer -> integer)
                .filter(j -> !marks.contains(j))
                .map(j -> new int[]{i,j}))
        .filter(ij -> !marks.contains(ij[0]))
        .filter(ij -> someVerification(dtoList.get(ij[0]), dtoList.get(ij[1])))
        .forEach(ij -> {
            marks.add(ij[0]);
            marks.add(ij[1]);
        })
        ;

    List<Object> objsToRemove = marks.stream()
        .map(i -> dtoList.get(i))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

    objsToRemove.forEach(obj -> dtoList.remove(obj));

    System.out.println("After: " + dtoList.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",", "[", "]")));

}

private static boolean someVerification(Object object, Object object2) {
    return object.equals(object2);
}
```

It's not the recommended way to use Stream API as it is doing mutation on `forEach` and the eventual execution depends on this side effect.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of code for refactoring two loops

Comment: I agree. I would not use it myself.